# Get all radcombobox client id dynamically

Tags: telerik, radcombobox

In Telerik Control, how to get a radcombobox id?

For example, the below code gets the value of RadCombox1 Client ID. If there is 5 radcomboboxes in my page (sample.aspx), how to get the corresponding id **DYNAMICALLY**.........

```
    {
    var combo = $find("<%= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>");
    }
```

Thanks in Advance,
Ganesan A

### Added More :

Thanks for your quick reply. Am using Telerik Control in **c#**.

a) am using no of radcombobox, raddatepicker, radtimepicker and raddatetimpicker in one page like below

```
    <telerik:RadSplitter ID="RadSplitter1" runat="server" OnClientLoaded="OnClientLoaded">
            <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane1" runat="server">
                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" CssClass="cmb_bx" runat="server">
                    <Items>
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem1" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem2" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem3" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem4" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem5" />
                    </Items>
                    <CollapseAnimation Duration="200" Type="OutQuint" />
                </telerik:RadComboBox>
                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ComboBox" CssClass="cmb_bx" runat="server">
                    <Items>
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem1" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem2" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem3" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem4" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem5" />
                    </Items>
                    <CollapseAnimation Duration="200" Type="OutQuint" />
                </telerik:RadComboBox>
                <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1" runat="server">
                </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="SupplierName" runat="server">
                </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="CorporateCode" runat="server">
                </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="PartNo" runat="server">
                </telerik:RadDatePicker>
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />    
            </telerik:RadPane>
            <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane2" runat="server">
            </telerik:RadPane>
        </telerik:RadSplitter>
```

b) when i scroll the page, radcombobox or any other control which i had mentioned above also scrolling with the page. it doesn't hide. So i am using the below javascript coding

```
    <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnClientLoaded(sender, eventArgs)
        {
          var pane = sender.getPaneById("<%= RadPane1.ClientID %>");
          var contentElement = pane.getContentElement();
          contentElement.onscroll = function () {
               var combo = $find("<%= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>");
             alert(combo.get_id());
              var dtpkr = $find("<%= RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>");
              var dropDown = combo.get_dropDownVisible();
              var dropDown1 = dtpkr.isPopupVisible();
              if (dropDown) {
                  combo.hideDropDown();
              }
              else if (dropDown1) {
                  dtpkr.togglePopup();
              }
          };
  }
        </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

c) This will hide RadcomboBox1 and RadDatePicker1 only. How can i write the code for more than one Radcombobox and Raddatepicker in one page.

Thanks
Ganesan A

Comment: Why don't you call the `$find` function 5 times in that case?

Comment: If the controls are comes dynamically means, how can we resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify what language, but this might help.  This is for C#.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    string comboBoxName = "RadComboBox" + i.ToString();
    var comboObject = (this.FindName(comboBoxName) as RadComboBox); //this returns the object if the name is found
    //access the clientID
    if( comboObject != null)
       var clientid = comboObject.ClientID;

}
```

Comment: whatever language he is using (C# or VB), his example uses client-side code. (so jquery and/or javascript would be needed)

Comment: Please check my Added More portion in the above

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know what to do with the RadComboBoxes and RadDatePickers once you have them, I'll simply point out [how to grab all the RadControls of a particular type](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/general/how-to-create-a-javascript-array-of-all-particular-radcontrols-on-the-page.aspx) and let you augment your code.